# ScheduledExecutorService slips for 10 minutes on a 1 minute schedule (systemd - journald fault)

Tags: java, multithreading, systemd, scheduledexecutorservice, journal

I have an executor service that is supposed to write some things to disk every minute.

It is scheduled like this:

```
    scheduledCacheDump = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    scheduledCacheDump.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::saveCachedRecords,
                                           60,
                                           60,
                                           TimeUnit.SECONDS
    );
```

The task uses a shared list that is filled by the main thread, so it is synchronized on that list:

```
   private void saveCachedRecords() {
        LOG.info(String.format("Scheduled record dump to disk. We have %d records to save.", recordCache.size()));
        synchronized (recordCache) {
            Iterator<Record> iterator = recordCache.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
               // save record to disk
               iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

My list is declared as such:

```
private final List<Record> recordCache = new ArrayList<>();
```

The main thread receives data by batch, so every second or so, it receives 30 records that it caches in the list. The rest of the time it is waiting on a socket.

What I don't understand, is that from the logs, my scheduled task is often triggered with way more that 1 minute in between:

`sept. 16 09:30:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:31:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:32:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:33:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:34:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:35:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:42:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:43:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:44:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:45:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:46:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:55:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:56:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:57:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:58:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 09:59:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 10:04:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 10:05:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
sept. 16 10:06:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.`

Look at this:

- sept. 16 09:59:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
- sept. 16 10:04:43 Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.

=> 5 minutes

Or even:

- sept. 16 **09:46:43** Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.
- sept. 16 **09:55:43** Scheduled record dump to disk. We have 27 records to save.

=> 9 minutes

My log is in the `synchronized()` scope, so I don't know if the task is actually scheduled on time and waits 10 minutes on the lock, or if it is just a real scheduling issue. I will be moving it out of it, but generally I can't fathom how a thread could stay blocked for 10 minutes on a lock that is released about every second.

How can I investigate this?

For information: the machine on which it runs is a KVM machine, could this be a factor?

Comment: Have you checked the GC activity?

Comment: I didn't. Is there a CLI tool to do that (I'm no expert in Java admin I admit)

Comment: not related to your problem but consider using a ConcurrentLinkedQueue instead of an ArrayList, it is thread safe out of the box and a Queue seems to be much more appropriate than a List for your need

Comment: What is the heap size?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Not necessarily. My list has a fairly constant amount of records (27), but each record is manipulated every second to add a data to it. When I dump it to disk, I empty the list completely and start over. So A ConcurrentLinkedQueue wouldn't be that good because I still have to sync() on the record modification somehow.

Comment: You should launch jconsole or jvisualvm to check how your heap evolves and to check the activity of your GC. A full GC may stop-the-world according to the GC algorithm used

Comment: What I don't understand is that schedules are skipped entirely instead of slipping. Fixed-rate scheduler should let the delayed task run as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my..

This was not Java's fault at all. This was systemd's fault.

My process runs as a systemd service, so the logs I pull come from systemd-journald.
And guess what, there's a rate limiting in systemd. And my daemon would hit it when the scheduler was triggered, so I got PLENTY of lines like this:

`Suppressed 570 messages from /system.slice/xxx.service
Suppressed 769 messages from /system.slice/xxx.service
Suppressed 745 messages from /system.slice/xxx.service
Suppressed 729 messages from /system.slice/xxx.service
Suppressed 717 messages from /system.slice/xxx.service
Suppressed 95 messages from /system.slice/xxx.service
Suppressed 543 messages from /system.slice/xxx.service`

So.. yeah, I removed the throttling on journald and I have my traces every minute now.

The solution was:

- edit `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`
- add line: `RateLimitInterval=0` at the end
- execute `systemctl restart systemd-journald`
- execute `systemctl restart myservice`

Now I have all things going smoothly.

I'll update the title for future reference :)

Comment: Which really means you should fix your *other* code not to spam so much. Hitting the rate limit means your daemon logs more than 1K messages within 30s by default. Removing the rate limit altogether is going to be bad for your logs when something *else* goes berserk. (wpa_supplicant or NetworkManager, say.)

Comment: This is for a production machine, we receive 30 messages per second, with 2 lines per message, so it outputs 3600 messages per minute. It is *very* compressible (our logrotate compresses 2GB of logs into 17MB), but we need them, so we won't rate limit them.. I would agree with you for a user-facing program though.

Comment: well in that case you know what the rate limit for your specific service should be, and you should be able to set it just for your service in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf.d/your_service_name.conf`without impacting the system wide default.

Comment: Good catch, I'll do that.